# @font face, calling a font-family works for one class but not for another, why?

Tags: css, wordpress, font-face, font-family

as described in the heading. I spent some time on implementing a specific font on a client's website. I implemented the font mostly on all the css classes where I need it.

Somehow on the "a" class which defines the menu links it doesn't work calling the font. Why?

See screenshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7FPp.png) and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HezRk.png).

On the class "div.powered-by" (which is also working like a link) for example it works and on the "a" class (which defines the menu links) it doesn't. See screenshots.

Calling the font doesn't work:

[image: Pic 1]

div.powered-by calling the font works:

[image: Pic 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the following line runs before your font-family

```
--primary-nav--font-family: var(--global--font-secondary);
```

You can use !important

```
a {
    font-family: 'Lemon Sans Uni Regular', Arial, sans-serif !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Can you also tell me what class I need to call when I want to make a selected page link in a certain color?

Comment: The page you are currently in
.primary-navigation .current-menu-item > a:first-child, .primary-navigation .current_page_item > a:first-child